# Display credit in map composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-print-layouts

I am trying to publish maps from QGIS Map Composer.

I would like to automatically add the credits of the background layers displayed in the composition (like OSM, Bing, ...)

I am aware of such a feature in main QGIS window using 
`View -> Decorations -> Copyright label` but

- this data is not shown in composer
- I am looking for an expression to adapt the text depending of the active layer

(Currently using either qgis 2.18 or 3.4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Please read everything**, there are some updates starting from QGIS **3.4** to QGIS **3.18**.

**In QGIS 3.4**, you can build your attribution label automatically, according to layers which are visible.

First, you need to setup metadata for all your layers.

**In QGIS 3.4.0 or 3.4.4**, you had to use the `QGIS Server` panel and fill the `attribution` field:
[image: QGIS Server panel]

**Since QGIS 3.4.5**, you can use the `Metadata` panel:
[image: Metadata panel]

In my project, I have 3 layers, but 2 layers have the same attribution `Provider 2`.

Then, in your layout, give an `itemID` to your map:

[image: itemID for map]

Then, in your label, you can create an expression like this:

```
array_to_string( -- 4 we make the attribution list unique and convert to string
    array_distinct(
        array_foreach( --2 for each layer in the map1
            map_get(item_variables('map1'),'map_layers')  --1 get the list of layers in the map1
            ,array_to_string(
                -- 3 we fetch the attribution for the layer
                layer_property(@element,'attribution')))))
```

Try to understand the expression by reading comments from 1 to 4.

This will render the correct attribution based on layers which are visible in my map. It will also remove attributions which are the same across layers.

[image: my label with expression]

**In QGIS 3.6.0**, you can add the `array_sort` expression to sort alphabetically.

**In QGIS 3.18**, there is now a `map_credits( 'Main Map' )` expression function which does all the `array_foreach`, `layer_properties` etc ... !

Comment: This works nicely for basemap layers. But as soon as you display a vector layer which has no 'Rights' metadata, the expression breaks.

Comment: Which expression are you talking about ? Which example because according to the QGIS Version, there is different possibilities

Comment: I'm using 3.16. And I used your expression under your section: 'Since QGIS 3.4.5...'. The expression starts with `array_to_string( -- 4 we`. It works very well if you have layers containing 'Rights' metadata in the Metadata panel. But I added a new layer (with no 'Rights' metadata) to the project which broke things (ie. the text label in my Layout started showing the raw expression string).

Comment: I can't try right now. Maybe we need to tweak the expression to add a defulat empty string if now rights, with `coalesce` ?

Answer (score 1):

One answer to your question can be a union of the great answers (in fact, your question is almost a duplicate) of this one: [Automating citation of data source in QGIS print composer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304822/automating-citation-of-data-source-in-qgis-print-composer)

- Add a new text label to the layout.
- In the item properties of the label, main properties, click on *Insert an Expression*.
- In the expression builder, switch to the *Function Editor* tab, and paste this code:

```
# Be sure to import iface from qgis.utils

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def get_layer_name(feature, parent):
    return qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer().name()
```

Its define a new *get_layer_name()* function that returns the name of the active layer and can be found under the *Custom* group of the expressions list.

- Click on *Save and Load Function*.
- Switch to the *Expression* tab and write this expression:

`layer_property( get_layer_name(), 'attribution')`

It returns the Attribution metadata of the active layer.

Don't forget to refresh the layout view when the active layer has changed.

Comment: I would rename `get_layer_name` by `get_active_layer_name`. It's more explicit that you get the name only for the current selected layer. Note that this is working only for a single layer and if you have the python expression on each computer.